# GPS waypoint latitude and longitude

Tags: android, tags, gps, latitude-longitude, google-maps-android-api-2

I am making a GPS app on my phone using the Goggle Maps SDK.  I would like to add a feature to allow the user to get the latitude and longitude for a specific point simply by taping that point on the screen.

An example would be if there is a "what's this?" kind of function like there is on Google Maps, but on the phone version? And how would I do that in code?

Comment: So, if I understand your question, you already have Google Maps in your app and you just want to find the lat/long of the click, right?

Comment: Yes, the app is already on my phone and I would like to find the lat/long on click/screen hold

Comment: I'm still confused. Is the Google Maps app on your phone, or does YOUR app have the Google Maps SDK?

Comment: Sorry, this was my first post ever...
I have made an app using the google maps sdk so far and at the moment it only gets the current position with GPS
I am trying to get it to show other lat/long when i touch that position on the map on my phone.
If that is better :)

Comment: No problem, check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. First you need to extend `com.google.android.maps.Overlay` and override the `onTap` method:

```
class MOverlay extends Overlay {
        @Override
        public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView) {
            int latitude = p.getLatitudeE6();
            int longitude = p.getLongitudeE6();

            // Do whatever you need to do here.

            return true; // true means we handled the tap
        }

}
```

Then, you need to add this overlay to the list of overlays on the map. Assuming your activity is extending `MapActivity`, this code should work:

```
class MyActivity extends MapActivity {
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          // your code here

          MapView map = findViewById(R.id.map); // you can change this

          MOverlay clickCatcher = new MOverlay();
          List<Overlay> allOverlays = map.getOverlays();
          allOverlays.add(clickCatcher);
          map.invalidate();
          // All done!
     }
}
```

Hopefully that helps you. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time :)
I will implement it maybe on the week end and see how it goes.